# Android: How to set bash as default root shell?

Tags: android, linux, terminal

How do I make bash the default shell for "root" user in Android terminal emulator? I can change the initial command in settings, but when I use 'su' to become root, I'm back in sh.

Comment: IMPOSSIBLE! it is hard coded inside bionic libc, and is unchangeable. unless you recompile your firmware.

Answer (score 4):

What I just did is move `/system/bin/sh` to`/system/bin/sh_old` and linked `/system/xbin/bash` to `/system/bin/sh`.  Seemed to work for me.  The only thing I'm working on is setting up my custom prompt.

Of course, if your bash isn't in xbin, then use the appropriate directory ;)

Comment: This is a very bad idea. The system will have all sorts of shell scripts which are set to execute under /system/bin/sh. If they are executed under bash instead they may not execute correctly.

Comment: @MJWalsh bash is down compatible to sh, so there should be no problem